# How to send image using OUTPUTSTREAM over Bluetooth connection in android?

Tags: android, sockets, bluetooth

I am creating an Android app and i would like to send image using outputStream and receive using InputStream . Help plzz

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11475168/example-how-to-send-big-images-over-bluetooth-and-also-more-text-data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked at the Bluetooth Chat sample in the SDK?

http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/BluetoothChat/src/com/example/android/BluetoothChat/BluetoothChatService.html

The ConnectedThread inner class in the class above shows you to read and write text data over bluetooth. The data is sent in bytes, so you can use it for any type of data.

Comment: yes i hav look that code , but how retrnasform those bytes back into image ?

Comment: Try using this BitmapFactory class. It lets you convert a byte array or InputStream into a bitmap http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html

Comment: Thank you :-) this is what i was searching for .

Comment: I want to send ( name , email , contact , picture ) from           phone1--->phone2 through outputStream/InputStream how i differentiate that these bytes are for name , email , what bytes are for picture . Help me plzz

Comment: Maybe create an object for all that data and serialize it? It's up to you how you want to do it, there's tons of ways. That's one suggestion. You can read this about serializing objects and converting  the raw bytes back to an object: http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/serialization/